# Localizable.strings (English) doesn't work but InfoPlist.strings (English) works?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

In .m file:

```
UIActionSheet *someSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
    initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TITLE", nil)
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL"
    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
    otherButtonTitles:@"option1", @"option2", nil
];
```

In `Localizable.strings (English)` i set `"TITLE" = "Share"`;

and in `InfoPlist.strings (English)` i set `CFBundleDisplayName="AppName123"`;

Then i switched my iphone's language to another one which has not been localized (Japanese for example).

In springboard the App's name did changed to **"AppName123"** but when running i saw "TITLE" where should be "Share".

The App has not been localized for Japanese, so why it did't use English as default?

Anyone can tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, you saw "TITLE", what have you done to get the value of the "TITLE"?

Comment: @Jacky Boy Sorry i forget to mention that , i used NSLocalizedString(@"TITLE", nil)

Comment: @1212e, if you have found a solution to your problem, you should post that as an answer, then mark that as the accepted answer by clicking the check symbol next to the new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED, `Simulator -> Erase all.`

Comment: could you please provide more details. I didn't find  that menu in either Xcode and iOS simulator

Comment: @user454083 It's `iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings` in iOS simulator version 6

Answer (score 5):

Please Try this Code

In Localizable.strings file

```
"FirstName" = "XYZ";
```

In Your .m file

```
NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(@"FirstName",@"");
```

or

```
NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(@"FirstName",nil);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody had a similar problem as I did:

I forgot to use semicolons in both files. I put semicolons in a InfoPlist.strings file and forgot to put them in Localizable.strings file.

```
"Cancel" = "Отмена";
"Connecting ..." = "Подключение ...";
```

Semicolons must be there. Do not forget.

Answer (score 1):

In one of projects I have situation like this:
1) I have localizable.strings (which has inside English, it, fr, de) containing translations like this one:

```
/* comment for translation */
"KeyString" = "ValueString";
```

2) then I use LocalizedStrings slightly different, with two arguments, like this:

```
_myString = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyString", @"Comment for translation");
```

It is working great, when I set to other language (like polish) I have English translations.

Hope it helps :)
F.

Comment: I added some comment `initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TITLE", @"some comment")` but it still dosen't work :(

Comment: did you created lizable.strings with for example "English" then add some other available translations?

Comment: btw did you used the same comemnt in translation and in NSLocalizedString?

Comment: Hi Filip,problem solved, the ANSWER is at the beginning of my question. Thanks anyway ! :)